# Super key is always pressed on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 20.04

I recently Upgraded Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04 LTS on an Asus laptop, but from beginning i couldn't type certain characters like `s`, `m`, `n` or even `space`. Instead these act like shortcuts.

For example when i only press `p`, it does `super + p` which changes the display mode. I can only type characters which there is no `super + key` shortcut for them.

It's not a hardware problem since my keyboard works fine with unity and windows. How can i solve it?